# Equivalent of Java Scanner class in Haxe

Tags: haxe

In the Haxe programming language, is there anything equivalent to Java's scanner class (which reads input from the command line?) I'd like to find some way of reading text input from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sys.stdin().readLine()` is what you're looking for.

Here's an example from http://haxe.org/doc/start/neko#reading-user-input:

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        Sys.println("What's your name?");
        var input = Sys.stdin().readLine();
        Sys.println(Std.format("Hello ${input}"));
        Sys.exit(0);
    }
}
```